# Why am I getting "sre_constants.error: bad character in group name" with ASCII group names?

Tags: python, regex

This is my regex:

```
(?P=<streetname>[a-zæøå ]+)(?:[ ]+)(?P=<housenumber>\d+)(?:[ ]+),(?:[ ]+)(?P=<postalcode>\d{1,4})(?:[ ]+)(?P=<city>[a-zæøå ]+)
```

All the group names contain only ASCII characters, so why the error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addrtools.py", line 46, in 
    main()
  File "addrtools.py", line 43, in main
    extract_address('Testaddress 15B, 1234 Oslo')
  File "addrtools.py", line 35, in extract_address
    match = re.match(pat_full, string)
  File "/Users/tomas/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/Users/tomas/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character in group name
```

I have confirmed that `pat_full` does indeed contain the above regular expression. Also, my document is encoded in UTF-8 and is set to UTF-8 mode (`# --*-- Encoding: UTF-8 --*--`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `(?P=<name>...)` patterns, which mean "Matches whatever text was matched by the earlier group named name". But you don't have any groups like `streetname` defined before.

Remove the `=` to make them actual named groups:

```
>>> re.compile('(?P<streetname>[a-zæøå ]+)(?:[ ]+)(?P<housenumber>\d+)(?:[ ]+),(?:[ ]+)(?P<postalcode>\d{1,4})(?:[ ]+)(?P<city>[a-zæøå ]+)')
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x102e6a620>
```

This is probably what you meant to do in the first place. :-)