# Python regex error: bad character in group name

Tags: python, regex

Can someone tell me why this regex works fine on oneline regex websites but not while using re.compile() in python.

I have used this website:
https://regex101.com/ and tested string is:

```
"test": "value"
```

Python code

```
x = r'((?(?=")(?:"(?(?<=\\)(?:.)|(?:[^")]))+")|(?:\w+)))(:|~)\s+((?(?=")(?:"(?(?<=\\)(?:.)|(?:[^"]))+")|(?:\w+)))'
re.compile(x)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character in group name
```

Comment: You are using conditionals in your regex, they are not supported by python re syntax. You should switch to python in regex101 when you are testing your patterns.

Comment: If you switch regex101 to Python mode it will also tell you it's broken.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks, got it.

Comment: Unknown downvoter, is it known to all that conditionals are not supported in python re? why isnt this a valid question?

Comment: Are you interested in a solution or just explanation?

Comment: I would be thankful if you provide an explanation

Comment: you can use the `regex` library instead of default one used by python..you can download it from **[here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)**

Comment: Just use `import regex as re` (`pip install regex` before) and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks, anyone knows why is it not implemented in python's re module

Answer (score 1):

From your example string and the regex101 output, it looks like you are trying to match a Python string with the general form:

```
"word": "word"
```

That is to say, a groups 1 and 3 are words that can either be in double quotes, or not quoted, but **no** hanging quotes, group 2 is a colon or tilde and can be followed by a whitespace character. So:

```
goodString = "\"test\": value"
badString = "test\": value"
```

The problem with your regex compile string actually hints towards the solution! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330519/why-am-i-getting-sre-constants-error-bad-character-in-group-name-with-ascii-g) sheds light on the returned error and the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) gives information on named groups.

By using named groups, you can make your expression shorter and more Pythonic!

```
x = r'((?P<a>\"?)\w+(?P=a))(:|~)\s+((?P<b>\"?)\w+(?P=b))'
```

For clarity:

```
group 1 = ((?P<a>\"?)\w+(?P=a))
group 2 = (:|~)\s+
group 3 = ((?P<b>\"?)\w+(?P=b))
```

Groups 1 and 3 capture the presence or absence of the quotation mark in a subgroup (a and b, respectively), then check for that subgroup at the end of the word.

You do not need to name the groups either! You could simply reference their number:

```
x = r'((\"?)\w+(\2))(:|~)\s+((\"?)\w+(\6))'
```

As a final test:

```
x = r'((\"?)\w+(\2))(:|~)\s+((\"?)\w+(\6))'
goodString = "\"test\": value"
badString = "test\": value"
print(re.match(x,goodString))
print(re.match(x,badString))
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='"test": value'>
None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want abilities beyond standard re, try this one:
https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex

It is a drop-in replacement of re, but supports many more new features, including conditional pattern.